# TortoiseGit - Slow Show Log Revision Query

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Currently we have a problem with `TorotiseGit - Show Log` taking ages to populate branch/tags history. On the other hand GIT GUI shows the revision all-most instantly. Though GIT GUI requires double clicking on the revision to see what's changed.

We have a repository with 300,000 files and recently about 3000 revisions ago, the administrator did a SVN move of one of the main directory's. Yes this means all 250,000 files where moved from one directory to the next. This may be the reason for the slow down.

Is there a way to speed up TorotiseGit to show log results faster in situations dealing with large svn repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cloned our SVN repository that contains 40-50 gigs of content. TortoiseGit
took 15 minutes to bring up a revision log of a single file. Though accessing the same revision log with the inbuilt GIT GUI was significantly faster.

It's been about 3-4 years since this original answer on stack overflow. Though the performance of TortoiseGit may have changed over the years and could be just as fast as the inbuilt GIT GUI. My recommendations if dealing with large 40-50 gig svn repro is to clone the svn repository and host it locally, or use the inbuilt GIT GUI.

Answer (score 2):

the answer is git doesn't have per file history, so it traverse the whole repository to build a single file history. with huge repository this becomes a problem.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem too - (almost) instant log view at root level and via git GUI, but 10's of minutes for an individual file via TGit.

Then (for unrelated reasons) our AntiVirus (not sure which - computers locked down) was disabled, and ... almost instant TGit log view of individual files!

So I guess that, for each fragment of log that was retrieved, the AV had to fire up and examine it piece by piece.

BTW our Repo is about 12GB and split into 1GB chunks